# What is the syntax for sftp -P (program) switch?

Tags: bash, sftp

What is the syntax for the -P switch in sftp?

I am trying ...

```
sftp -P /home/me/dev_bin/ssh user@hostname
```

... but the result is a usage statement ...

```
Attaching to /home/me/dev_bin/ssh...
usage: ssh [...]
```

I think that ssh is not seeing the rest of the command line.

Edit: This was a stupid question, but I am undecided about deleting it. Deleting it will preserve my vanity, but leaving it here would help some other victim of poor reading comprehension to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh -P port` Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host. (Port should be a number.)

I think you're looking for

`ssh -S program` Name of the program to use for the encrypted connection.  The program must understand ssh(1) options.

Both quotes (except for the parenthesized comment) extracted from `man sftp`

Comment: Mercy sakes. Thank you, rici!